# Drag and Drop in Office JS page to Word Document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office365, office-js, word-web-addins

I am creating an online office add-in for the Word application. I have created an HTML page with some fields like, Name, Address, Mobile etc.
On drag and drop of such a field I want to create a MergeField in Word Document.

I have done R&D regarding drag and drop but I am not able to find how to control a drop event outside of the container.

Is there any way to fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to browser limitations we don’t currently support drag and drop from the taskpane to the word surface.

But what many developers have implemented is a ‘+’ button to add items into the document, or other sorts of events like dbl click.

Comment: This post is 4 years old. Do we have any update on this? Is it still not supported ?

Comment: Anyone have implemented such functionality?